# iOS 17 AppIntent and requesting confirmation for widgets

Tags: ios, appintents

I have a home widget with buttons (new in iOS 17).
In order to prevent taking action if the user taps on the widget buttons accidentally, I want to ask the user for confirmation.

It appeared that `requestConfirmation` be exactly what I needed, but no confirmation view shows up when I invoke this method in the `perform` function.

I have tried the following:

```
        try await requestConfirmation(result: .result(dialog: "Are you sure you want to do this?") {
            Image(.mdlsWhite)
        })
```

and this alternative:

```
        let confirmed: Bool = try await $name.requestConfirmation(for: self.name,
                                                                         dialog: IntentDialog(stringLiteral: msg))
```

Neither option work.

I am starting to think that the `requestConfirmation` is not to be used with Home Widgets.

Is there a better way to handle confirmations for buttons included in a Home Widget?

Comment: No. Instead of confirmation, I require double tap on the buttons